# Problems using seekg in C++

Tags: c++, file, stream, seekg

I'm reading a file through a function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
...
void readfile(string name){

    string line;
    int p = 0;
    ifstream f(name.c_str());

    while(getline(f,line)){
        p++;
    }
    f.seekg(0);
    cout << p << endl;        

    getline(f,line);
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Mi file has 3 lines:

```
first
second
third
```

I expected the output:

```
3
first
```

Instead I get:

```
3
(nothing)
```

why is my seekg not working?

Comment: What happens if you do `f.clear()` before you use `seekg`?

Comment: @sftrabbit ... what happens? it works... thank you, that was fast.

Comment: Note that `seekg` itself clears `eofbit` since C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `seekg()` fails if the stream has reached the end of the file (`eofbit` is set), which occurs due to your `getline` looping. As sftrabbit implies, calling `clear()` will reset that bit and should allow you to seek properly. (Or you could just use C++11, in which `seekg` will clear `eofbit` itself.)

Comment: Apparently in C++11 `seekg` will automatically clear `eofbit`.

Comment: @sftrabbit One of C++11's many improvements. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @sftrabbit Will it also set the `failbit`?  Because the first loop will only stop when the input fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use iterators for read from the file

```
std::fstream file( "myfile.txt", std::ios::out );
std::string data = std::string(
     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( file ),
     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
```

Comment: Iterators are nice, but the question was regarding why the method provided does not work, not if there is a better method (and all you're doing is shifting the work from file routines to operations on a string, which could also be done via iterators but says nothing about the original problem).